# Boostrap modal not showing on ASP.NET GridView template button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have ASP.NET project working with bootstrap. I need to control when to show or hide the modals in a Web page. It works well with any button but it doesn't work from buttons in a GridView template field.

This is my page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           function ShowModItem() {
               $('#modItem').modal('show');
           }

           function HideModItem() {
               $('#modItem').modal('hide');
               $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
           }
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" UseAccessibleHeader="true" AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="ID">         
 <Columns>            
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" />            
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />            
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />            
  <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" />            
  <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">                
    <ItemTemplate>                    
      <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEditItem" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit-16.jpg" Text="Editar" OnClick="btnEditItem_Click"/>                
    </ItemTemplate>            
  </asp:TemplateField>        
 </Columns>    
</asp:GridView> 
<asp:Button ID="btnNewItem" runat="server" Text="New" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnNew_Click" />
<div class="modal fade" id="modBanco" role="dialog">
   <%--...Form with controls to add or edit item...--%>
</div>
```

And this is my code-behind:

```js
protected void btnNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ShowModItem();", true);
 }

protected void btnEditItem_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{     /*Code for setting current item values to controls*/
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ShowModItem();", true); 
}
```

Why does the modal shows well for "new" item and not for "edit" item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in the aspx page:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" UseAccessibleHeader="true" AllowSorting="true" OnRowCommand="gvItems_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" />
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEditItem" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="EditItem" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit-16.jpg" Text="Editar" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

As you can see the GridView now uses OnRowCommand. With this you can pass arguments like the ID you want to edit. In your code there was no way to see which item you wanted to edit. The CommandName has also been changed because if you use "Edit" the default RowEditing event is fired and this is not what you want.

And in code behind you handle the RowCommand:

```
    protected void gvItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "EditItem")
        {
            //get the ID of the item you want to edit
            string ID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            //launch the popup
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ShowModItem(" + ID + ");", true);
        }
    }
```

And for opening a popup for a new item there is no need to do it in code behind through a postback. Just use a normal button with an onclick event. This saves a roundtrip to the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your `gridview image button` attribute `onclick=btnModificarBanco_Click`. But your code behind event is `btnEditItem_Click`. So inside `gridview image button onclick` should be

```
 <ItemTemplate>                    
  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEditItem" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit-16.jpg" Text="Editar" OnClick="btnEditItem_Click"/>                
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Nagib, but it was a typo, my mistake! My actual controls are in spanish, so I forgot to translate that code. The actual code is exactly as you mentioned and it doesn't work, I've already edit the post to look correct.

Comment: Try it in `Row_Command` event 

     protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
        
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ShowModItem();", true); 
        }
        
        }